# Ipad Images WAY too large on universal app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview

I am working on a universal app and am trying to figure out my image sizes for Iphones and Ipad.

I set up my view to compact X any to represent the Iphone and put the UIImageView to the size that looks good when using the preview assistant editor. Then I switched to the Regular x Regular view to represent the Ipad and scaled my UIImageView down to the point where it is so thin I can barely see it yet on the preview assistant editor the UIImageView still covers more than 1/3 of the Ipad screen.

How can I fix this issue? (I've only ever worked on Iphone apps so I apologize if this is very basic)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `wAny hAny`. Then you can use auto-layout to size your image. Once you set it up correctly, then the image will size according to the device size.

Here are a couple tutorials to get you started with auto layout:

- [appCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)
- [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)
- [Site Point](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/)

Comment: I'm using auto layout and the same problem occurs when I am in wAny Hany as it does in Wregular Hregular. I have a UIImageView that's fine with any width I add to it but the height is always way too big. Even if I specify that that height is 5, both in the simulator and the preview screen will show it take up about a third of the screen.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the storyboard with the constraints?